# Mysql select with multiple condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I would need help creating a query
Table A

```
+------------+--------------------+-------+
| product_id | name               | price |
+------------+--------------------+-------+
|         13 | Product 13         |     5 |
|         14 | Product 14         |     2 |
|         15 | Product 15         |     3 |
|         16 | Product 16         |     2 |
|         17 | Product 17         |    15 |
+------------+--------------------+-------+
```

Table B

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | product_id | taxonomy_id |
+----+------------+-------------+
| 10 |         13 |           5 |
| 11 |         13 |           2 |
| 12 |         14 |           3 |
| 13 |         15 |           2 |
| 14 |         16 |          15 |
| 14 |         16 |           5 |
| 14 |         16 |          19 |
| 14 |         16 |          21 |
| 14 |         16 |          18 |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

my attempt

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.product_id = A.product_id 
WHERE IF(B.taxonomy_id IN ('5','15'), 
         IF(B.taxonomy_id IN ('2'), 1, 0), 0) = 1
GROUP BY A.product_id
```

I need it to give me back those results from table A for which it is true

**B.taxonomy_id is "5" OR "15" and B.taxonomy_id is "2"**

The result would be for this example -> `product_id - 13` 
and I also need to get a number of results  `SELECT count(*) ...` -> `return is 1`

Comment: what is your expected result

Comment: [the reason why you should always have a primary/unique key when using innoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232919/mysql-table-with-composite-index-but-not-primary-key/57233092#57233092) .. without primary/unique key you are more or less down grading InnoDB 's multithreaded performance to MyISAM which locks..

Comment: your current `where` clause will only yield results whose `taxonomy_id` is not in `[5, 15, 2]` because once it goes true in `B.taxonomy_id IN ('5', '15')` it goes straight to `B.taxonomy_id IN ('2')` which will yield false, which leads to `0`. I suggest shortening it into `B.taxonomy_id IN ('2', '5', 15)`

Answer (score 1):

Is it normal that your tables don't have an id column as a unique primary key ?

Anyway, here is what I came across, tell me if it works :

```sql
SELECT table_nameA.product_id
FROM table_nameA
LEFT JOIN table_nameB on table_nameA.product_id = table_nameB.product_id
WHERE taxonomy_id = 2 AND table_nameA.product_id IN
    (SELECT table_nameA.product_id
    FROM table_nameA
    LEFT JOIN table_nameB on table_nameA.product_id = table_nameB.product_id
    where taxonomy_id = 5 or taxonomy_id = 15
    GROUP BY table_nameA.product_id, taxonomy_id)
```

Result is :

```
| product_id |
|------------|
|         13 |
```

About your count query, it is exactly the same.

```sql
SELECT count(table_nameA.product_id) as Quantity
FROM table_nameA
LEFT JOIN table_nameB on table_nameA.product_id = table_nameB.product_id
WHERE taxonomy_id = 2 AND table_nameA.product_id IN
    (SELECT table_nameA.product_id
    FROM table_nameA
    LEFT JOIN table_nameB on table_nameA.product_id = table_nameB.product_id
    where taxonomy_id = 5 or taxonomy_id = 15
    GROUP BY table_nameA.product_id, taxonomy_id)
```

Result is :

```
| Quantity |
|----------|
|        1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing filtering in the `WHERE` clause; you need to do this conditional filtering inside the `HAVING` clause. You can avoid `LEFT JOIN`, as the product should have taxonomies for them (2 AND (5 or 15)):

```
SELECT a.product_id 
FROM tablea a 
JOIN tableb b on b.product_id = a.product_id 
GROUP BY a.product_id 
HAVING SUM(b.taxonomy_id IN (5,15)) 
       AND SUM(b.taxonomy_id = 2)
```

**Result**

```
| product_id |
| ---------- |
| 13         |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcaFzGhEiMja6jwtC2gHFU/1)

Comment: The problem is when I want to get -> SELECT COUNT(a.product) ... return is 2

Comment: @user3061527 why are you doing `select count(..)` ? That is not required as per your original problem statement. Please explain further, because it seems you want to do something totally different that your original query.

Comment: I want the original query but also the query to get the count

Comment: @user3061527 add expected result in tabular format (like they way you have given the table data) into the question. Then only some clarity would appear.

Comment: @user3061527 you cannot get count in the same query (unless we use a subquery([Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) and windowing functions). But the good thing is that you can access the `num_rows` member of mysqli object to get the count indirectly, while your main query gives you all the product_id in separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1
              from b
              where b.product_id = a.product_id and
                    b.taxonomy_id in (5, 15)
             ) and
       exists (select 1
              from b
              where b.product_id = a.product_id and
                    b.taxonomy_id in (2)
             ) ;
```

If you just wanted the `product_id`s, then I would recommend aggregation:

```
select b.product_id
from b
where b.taxonomy_id in (2, 5, 15)
group by b.product_id
having sum( b.taxonomy_id in (5, 15) ) > 0 and
       sum( b.taxonomy_id in (2) ) > 0 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either join with having clause or intersect function with 2 queries to get the output

> 13

in your senario.
Join with having clause:

```
select a.product_id from a inner join b on a.product_id = b.product_id group by a.product_id having (SUM (b.taxonomy_id IN (5,15)) and SUM (b.taxonomy_id in (2)));
```

Intersect with 2 queries:

```
select a.product_id from a where (a.product_id IN (select product_id from b where b.taxonomy_id = 2))
INTERSECT
select a.product_id from a where (a.product_id IN (select product_id from b where b.taxonomy_id in (5,15)));
```

For count use something like this which will return

> 1

as an output:

```
select COUNT(*) from (select a.product_id from a where (a.product_id IN (select product_id from b where b.taxonomy_id = 2))
INTERSECT
select a.product_id from a where (a.product_id IN (select product_id from b where b.taxonomy_id in (5,15)))) I;
```