# Mysql Indexing is not working on a particular table

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have a large set of data in the MySQL version 5.6
And Suppose name columnA, columnB, & columnC.

columnA(bigint)  columnB(bigint) Time(timestamp)

Where I have applied BTREE UNIQUE INDEXING.

But When I explaining my query, I am getting all rows traversed.

I have tried to Analyze, Repair table but no luck.

Note:

In different tables, I am getting expected result after applying to index.

The size of columnA(bigint 20) where I am having an issue, is more than 50,000.

I want one row traversed after indexing.

Mysql database storage shows 0B on Index.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA ( ColumnA bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
                      ColumnB bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
                      ColumnC bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
                      ColumnD bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
                      ColumnE timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
                    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `TableA`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `idx_npp_pid` (`ColumnA`),
  ADD KEY `idx_npp_uid` (`ColumnD`);
COMMIT;

EXPLAIN SELECT `ColumnA` FROM `TableA` WHERE `ColumnA`=4444;
```

Explain Result:

```
id select_type    table    type    possible_keys   key    key_len    ref   rows   Extra 
1  SIMPLE         TableA   ALL     NULL            NULL   NULL       NULL  132244     Using where
```

Comment: can you show as the create table? `show create table <your table's name>`

Comment: What is the query that you are running ? Without knowing about the query, and its `EXPLAIN..` plan, it is hard to help in "*I want one row traversed after indexing*"

Comment: CREATE TABLE `TableA` (
  `ColumnA` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ColumnB ` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ColumnC` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ColumnD` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ColumnE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `TableA`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `idx_npp_pid` (`ColumnA`),
  ADD KEY `idx_npp_uid` (`ColumnD`);
COMMIT;

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Its shows all rows traversed, EXPLAIN SELECT `ColumnA` FROM `TableA` WHERE `ColumnA`=4444;

Comment: @SurajAnand comments are not the place to write these queries. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58096726/edit) your original question and add all the details here. Also, if you want the community to help generously, please read this first: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: @SurajAnand is your MySQL version 5.3 ? If yes, it is pretty old and you should upgrade to latest. Do `Select Version();` and edit the question and add the actual version number. Also, add the complete result of `explain..` statement to the question also.

Comment: @SurajAnand do you actually have a row with Column A value equal to 4444 ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes sir.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ColumnA FROM TableA WHERE ColumnA=4444;` -- there may be some extra clues there.

Comment: I see `5.6` and `5.3` -- Which version is it?  MySQL never had a 5.3, though MariaDB did.  Anyway, the actions of InnoDB have been as discussed here, even at least as far back as version 4.1.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - The 'cost' model fails to notice SSD vs HDD.  Also, I have never seen any version shun an index when doing a point query on a table with 132K rows.  The cutoff works out to be somewhere around 20%; I don't think I have seen it go below 10%.

Comment: @SurajAnand - Let's figure out whether the bug is in the Optimizer or in Explain.  Please do this:  `FLUSH STATUS;  SELECT ColumnA FROM TableA WHERE ColumnA=4444;  SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`

Comment: @RickJames yes i am aware of the fact that MySQL can't use hardware related based calcucations..   What i meant is it that a SSD can stream data much faster then a HDD can... But when looking back at the comment i descriped it wrong..

Answer (score 1):

> Mysql database storage shows 0B on Index.

InnoDB always needs a Primary Key, because it clusters the Primary Key with Data (and that is why it is also called as Clustered Index). That is why, there is no explicit disk storage for Index, when there is only Primary Key defined on an InnoDB table.

Now, if you don't explicitly define a Primary Key, InnoDB looks for the first Unique Key which is NOT NULL also, to be implicitly defined as Primary Key. If no such key is available, it creates a hidden Primary Key. So, it is always better to define a Primary Key. In your case, it has implicitly considered ColumnA as the primary key because it is UNIQUE and NOT NULL.

If no Natural Primary Key (combination) is available, then people generally advise to define a Surrogate Primary Key, using auto_increment.

Get more details here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html

> But When I explaining my query, I am getting all rows traversed.

You need to provide us your `EXPLAIN..` plan result, to be able to come to some conclusion.

Comment: *"InnoDB always needs a Primary Key ... "* indeed InnoDB makes a internal ROW_ID which does more harm then good when you forget to make a primary or unique key yourself -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232919/mysql-table-with-composite-index-but-not-primary-key/57233092#57233092 .. Not defining a primary/unique in innoDB would mean InnoDB could "table lock" like MyISAM

Comment: *"If no Natural Primary Key (combination) is available, then people generally advise to define a Surrogate Primary Key, using auto_increment."* For innoDB i would generally advice to always have a `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` column especially for a heavy `INSERTing` environment as InnoDB engine is [optimized](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) for that usage as inserts in the index happens in a order.. Using a Natural or Surrogate key as primary key can cause index rebuilds when randomness happen meaning slower inserts..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks. second point is a good insight. In general, I prefer to see if the composite primary key is going to be too heavy, then avoid defining it as PK and use a surrogate key only; because Innodb clusters all secondary indexes also with PK, making them heavy as well

Comment: *" because Innodb clusters all secondary indexes also with PK, making them heavy as well –"* indeed very true.. in RMDS thoery when two or more indexes are needed in the table indexes are better off to be non clusted in general..

Comment: ... If i am not mistaken InnoDB secondary indexes stores the clusterd key location and the clusterd key data...Which means if you do `SELECT * FROM t WHERE secondary_index_column = 1` MySQL also need to load the clusterd key entry from memory or disk to get the ROW_ID to load the table data.. Meaning more ram/disk i/o is needed.. Well it might be a "small" overhead in most cases as indexes are stored in pages in the memory or disk. But Ideally i would vote for the option that MySQL devs would include a option to allow non clusterd or clusted indexing to be build/used for the InnoDB engine..

Comment: @RaymondNijland - A lookup by a secondary key drills down 2 BTrees -- the secondary index and the clustered index.  The number of levels in, say, a billion-row table (or index) is typically about 5.  So your sample Select would need to fetch about 10 blocks from disk or, more likely, find most of them cached in the buffer_pool.

Comment: *"A lookup by a secondary key drills down 2 BTrees -- the secondary index and the clustered index."*  Yes indeed thanks @RickJames  for confirming..