# How to join two tables using different ID but are related

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch data from the parent table using a child table but there seems to be an error I am doing while trying to implement this

I have tried to use a join statement but fail every time upon executing the statement. The code should fetch the data using the following fields:

```
Parent table COMPETITIONS
     1. comp_id - linked to fixtures table
     2. comp_name


Parent table TEAMS:
     1. team_id - linked to home_teamID & away_teamID
     2. team_name
     3. team_email

Child table FIXTURES:
    1. fixture_id
    2. fixture_date
    3. fixture_time
    4. home_teamID - linked to the team's table [team_id]
    5. away_teamID - linked to the team's table [team_id]
    6. comp_id - linked to the competitions table
```

I tried using a join, but the error I get is that there an exception near the 'teams' clause of my "JOIN ON" syntax.

The expected results are a table that contains all the FIXTURES records which have been select or extracted from the parent tables. But the error I seem to get is that MySQL is not allowing me to access the TEAMS table using the field HOME_TEAMid and AWAY_TEAMid. However, both fields are related to the Teams table as aforementioned

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096726/mysql-indexing-is-not-working-on-a-particular-table/58097438?noredirect=1#comment102588882_58097438) as example data and expected results tells us more then "millions" of words...

Comment: The tells me that the HOME_TEAMid & AWAY_TEAMid are not UNIQUE but the data can be seen to be extracted from the PARENT table TEAMS; which has a field of PRIMARY KEY called team_id. Any concise explanation with this regard?

Comment: So... what does your query look like?

Comment: SELECT fixtures.fixture_id, fixtures.fixture_date, fixtures.fixture_time, fixtures.home_teamID, fixtures.away_teamID, competitions.comp_id FROM teams, fixtures, competitions JOIN teams on fixtures.home_teamID = teams.team_id JOIN teams on fixtures.away_teamID = teams.team_id JOIN competitions on fixtures.comp_id = competitions.comp_id

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT f.fixture_id, f.fixture_date,  f.fixture_time,
th.team_name as Hteam_name,
th.team_email AS Hteam_email,
ta.team_name  as Ateam_name,
ta.team_email as Ateam_email

FROM  FIXTURES as f

LEFT JOIN  TEAMS as th ON   f.home_teamID = th.team_id  -- HOME 
LEFT JOIN  TEAMS as ta ON   f.home_teamID = ta.team_id  -- AWAY

WHERE th.team_id = 123   -- any condition you like here
```

You can take advantage of table aliasing.