# Composite index for a relationship table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
    `student_id`            int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,        
    `student_name`          varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `courses` (
    `course_id`             int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,        
    `course_name`           varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`course_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `students_courses` (
    `id`                    int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,        
    `student_id`            int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `course_id`             int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Here, am using the `students_courses` table to store the relationships between the Students and Courses. Because one Student can enroll to more than one Course.

The doubt am having is, what should be indexed and how for that table.

1) Shall I index `student_id` and `course_id` separately like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `students_courses` (
    `id`                    int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,        
    `student_id`            int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `course_id`             int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY (`student_id`),
    KEY (`course_id`)
);
```

2) Or, create a composite index for both the `student_id` and `course_id`

```
CREATE TABLE `students_courses` (
    `id`                    int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,        
    `student_id`            int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `course_id`             int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY (`student_id`, `course_id`)
);
```

3) If going with composite key, should I remove that that `id` primary key and make the PRIMARY KEY composite?

I will be using this relationship table during JOIN mainly. So am a bit confused here.

Comment: i would always use a `id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` no matter what as InnoDB engine ia heavy optimizated for handling this [case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) .. As a composite key can be  more "random" making the insert most likely not always happen in order annymore in the index slowing down the inserting speeds

Comment: @RaymondNijland, sorry didn't get you. You mean no need of indexing the other fields? Or you are talking about including the `PRIMARY KEY` keyword like this: `id                   int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `

Comment: i mean always having a column with a AUTO_INCREMENT and a PRIMARY KEY yes ...  But on the other side as `KEY (student_id, course_id`)`  is a secondary index on InnoDB and if you join on `student_id` that means InnoDB has to load the `PRIMARY KEY(id)` from memory.disk aswell as the ROW_ID to the table is stored in there..  in a heavy write go for mine fast comment in a heavy select environment that composite key might be better..

Comment: @RaymondNijland for a plain mapping (one field to another field) table, I would rather prefer the natural composite key instead. Because, you anyways would need to define a UNIQUE key for data consistency. So, the overheads during insert are going to be there even if random inserts

Comment: *"Because, you anyways would need to define a UNIQUE key for data consistency. So, the overheads during insert are going to be there even if random inserts "* @MadhurBhaiya i know about the internal ROW_ID when you don't you dont use PRIMARY/UNIQUE key non defining does more harm then good [post of mine explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232919/mysql-table-with-composite-index-but-not-primary-key/57233092#57233092) ...     But like i explained InnoDB engine is more optimized into handling those inserts in "order" meaning using AUTO_INCREMENT vs composite keys

Comment: ... also @MadhurBhaiya ... in a heavy write environment go for the AUTO_INCREMENT in a heavy select environment that composite key should be better as using a  secondary index means that InnoDB has to load the PRIMARY KEY(id) from memory/disk aswell as the ROW_ID to the table is stored in there ..Note i mean the heavy read and or write offcource to be on the `students_courses` table ... But this seams to be student cource data so i am  assuming the reads will be more then the writes after reconsideration as i am assuming the cources are only added at the start of a year or around the finals..

Comment: @RaymondNijland agree with Read/Write environment difference. but in such extreme scenarios, there is no single solution; all require benchmarking. If OP is dealing with large tables, he should benchmark against both the approaches *vis-a-vis* space consumption, insert/update timings, and select speeds.

Comment: *"with Read/Write environment difference. but in such extreme scenarios, there is no single solution; all require benchmarking. I"* agreed.. @MadhurBhaiya mine statements was more meant as rule off thumb based on thoery which is found the MySQL manual.. Al offcource also depends on configration..

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Every `UNIQUE` key is checked before an `INSERT` can commit.  Non-unique keys are delayed (see "Change Buffering").  So having `PRIMARY KEY(id)` _slows down_ `INSERTs`.  (Noting that `UNIQUE (student, course)` is also required.)

Comment: i know @RickJames 's `PRIMARY KEY(id) AUTO_INCREMENT` should in thoery be faster vs  `UNIQUE (student, course)` **alone**  that was more or less the starting point of the complete sparring session..  As the `PRIMARY KEY(id) AUTO_INCREMENT` inserts into a order (at the end) in the index where `UNIQUE (student, course)` might be inserted between tree nodes and needs the index to be rebuild more often..

Comment: @RaymondNijland - I gotta mince words.  An index is never "rebuilt" (without an explicit requesting it).  On the other hand, blocks may be split, which costs something.  That cost happens regardless of whether the pair of columns is the PK or any other type of index.  Yes, there will be fewer block splits when always inserting at the 'end' of the BTree.

Comment: @RickJames yes i agree that “rebuild” was a wrong term for block splitting. But i am pretty sure InnoDB also reserve spaces in the index pages for future inserts so splitting might not happen at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we stick to using the Auto Increment `id` column as Primary Key. Now, we will also need to ensure that the data is consistent, *i.e.*, there are no duplicate rows for a combination of `(student_id, course_id)` values. So, we will need to either handle this in application code (do a select every time before insert/update), or we can fix this thing structurally by defining a Composite `UNIQUE` constraint on `(student_id, course_id)`.

Now, a Primary Key is basically a UNIQUE NOT NULL Key. If you look at your table definition, this newly defined UNIQUE constraint is basically a Primary Key only (because the fields are NOT NULL as well). So, in this particular case, you don't really need to use a Surrogate Primary key `id`.

The difference in overheads during random DML (Insert/Update/Delete) will be minimal, as you would also have similar overheads when using a UNIQUE index only. So, you can rather define a Natural Primary Composite Key `(student_id, course_id)`:

```sql
-- Drop the id column
ALTER TABLE students_courses DROP COLUMN id;

-- Add the composite Primary Key
ALTER TABLE students_courses ADD PRIMARY(student_id, course_id);
```

Above will also enforce the UNIQUE constraint on the combination of `(student_id, course_id)`. Moreover, you will save **4 bytes** per row (size of `int` is 4 bytes). This will come handly when you would have large tables.

Now, while Joining from `students` to `students_courses` table, above Primary Key will be a sufficient index. However, if you need to Join from `courses` to `students_courses` table, you will need another key for this purpose. So, you can define one more key on `course_id` as follows:

```sql
ALTER TABLE students_courses ADD INDEX (course_id);
```

Moreover, you should define Foreign Key constraints to ensure data integrity:

```sql
ALTER TABLE students_courses ADD FOREIGN KEY (student_id) 
                             REFERENCES students(student_id);

ALTER TABLE students_courses ADD FOREIGN KEY (course_id) 
                             REFERENCES courses(course_id);
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland but it also needs to update the UNIQUE index, right ? My point is that you anyways need to define a UNIQUE constraint. So, the overhead in updating that index tree will be on similar lines as updating this PK.

Comment: indeed, i need coffee badly it seams as i catched on way to late what you meant :-) if a `UNIQUE(student_id, course_id)` also is required i assume it is indeed required like you said.. Then the innodb 's AUTO_INCREMENT insert optimisation does not help much....

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Agreed.  The `id` has zero benefit, and some waste of space and speed.  In the end, you need 2 indexes:  PK(a,b), and INDEX(b,a).  Whether you say INDEX(b) or INDEX(b,a) probably does not matter at all.

Comment: The optimal result is effectively 2 BTrees -- one ordered by `(student, course)`, one ordered by `(course, student)`.  You need both of those indexes.  Neither will be inserting at the "end" of the table as would happen with the useless `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: Fewer BTrees to update on an `INSERT` => less work to do.

Comment: Or many inserts (~1000) in one committed transaction ... @RickJames also "less" work to do atleast it is (much) faster then 1000 separated query with auto commit enabled..   But why do we worry that much about premature insert performance anyway this is a students courses table which might only be "heavy" write used at the start of a study year or finals (like i sad before in the comments)

Comment: Every `COMMIT` requires at least one disk write (and fsync).  A single commit for 1000 rows saves 999 writes.