# MySQL InnoDB Composite Index Selectivity and Cardinality for Perfomance

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, innodb, cardinality

I would like to ask couple of questions about the order of columns in a composite index for InnoDB engine and about explanation of Cardinality and Selectivity that should be met (and how to do that) to get the best performance on the provided example.

1. What is the difference between Selectivity and Cardinality in the context of InnoDb composite index perfomance?
2. When should you put emphasis on Selectivity and when on Cardinality if you create a composite index?

Since InnoDB uses B-Tree (B-Tree+) index and a coposite index is searched starting from the leftmost column that the index is build from.

My understanding is that it makes sense to use such columns combination order that the leftmost column will throw the biggest not matching portion of the index out of the seek and continue with less data to search on,
the next column of the composite index should have the same property so all the others till the seek narrows the amount of rows
potentially matching to the smallest amount on which it can scan for exact matching rows.

In short what I understand the leftmost column should be the most coarse grained division of all rows and next columns of composite index shuold be more and more fine grained amounts of rows.

3. Is this Cardinality? and if the composite index is build this way as I described then is Cardinality high or low?
4. How about Selectivity? is this correlated to the Cardinality?

5.How to get the best Selectivity and Cardinality for table design as below?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_list` (
  `one` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `two` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `three` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `four` datetime NOT NULL,
  `five` DECIMAL(5,2)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

columns' maximum distinct count values will be:
`one` max 10;
`two` max 100;
`three` max 1000;
`four` max 36500; //100 years

second table for ad hoc joins:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `three_list` (
    `l_three` varchar(128) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Queries that will be issued:

(A) Query for specific `one`, `two`, `three`, `four`

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    `data_list`
WHERE 
    `one` = 'abc'
AND    
    `two` = 1
AND    
    `three` = 'xyz'
AND    
    `four` = '2018-01-01'
;
```

(B) Query for specific `one`, `two`, `three` and range of `four`

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    `data_list`
WHERE 
    `one` = 'abc'
AND    
    `two` = 1
AND    
    `three` = 'xyz'
AND    
    `four` >= '2018-01-01'
AND
    `four` < '2019-01-01'
ORDER BY
    `two`,
    `three`,
    `four`
;
```

(C) Query for specific `one`, `two` and any `three` within range of `four`

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    `data_list`
WHERE 
    `one` = 'abc'
AND    
    `two` = 1
AND    
    `four` >= '2018-01-01'
AND
    `four` < '2019-01-01'
ORDER BY
    `two`,
    `three`,
    `four`
;
```

(D) Query with `JOIN` for specific `one` and `two`, `three` being on the list `three_list` and `four` within the range

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    `data_list`
INNER JOIN 
    `three_list`
ON 
    `three` = `l_three`
WHERE 
    `one` = 'abc'
AND    
    `two` = 1
AND    
    `four` >= '2018-01-01'
AND
    `four` < '2019-01-01'
ORDER BY
    `two`,
    `three`,
    `four`
;
```

Perhaps the whole table design is flawed right from its beginning (ie due to not having PK `id` with auto_increment for `data_list`). This question is about the cardinality and selectivity for the best performance of composite index however an alternative table design is also welcomed in case there is no good columns' order choice for queries as above.

The most important performance to me is for SELECT statements. INSERTs are going to be rare (once a day) and UPDATE, DELETE are not going to be needed.

Rows must be unique in the `data_list` I mean the combination of `one`,`two`,`three`,`four` columns values.

Comment: *"My understanding is that it makes sense to use such columns combination order that the leftmost column *" True but from the other side when using more queries which possibly needs different composite indexing per query you also have to plan your indexes to keep the amount off indexing and the lenght as small of possible as indexes add a overhead for insert/delete/update queries..

Comment: ... General rule of thumb if the index size is bigger then the table size and that table is not a many-to-many relation table as those 90-95% of all cases only exists with two columns with a PRIMARY KEY on two columns you are overindexing..

Comment: @RaymondNijland What would you suggest? Having just one `id` column as `PK`, resign from composite index at all and put separate indexes on each column `one` to `four`? How to enforce data being unique for combination of these columns? Create a trigger before insert to check if the combination is not duplicated?

Comment: *"Perhaps the whole table design is flawed right from its beginning (ie due to not having PK id with auto_increment for data_list)."* innoDB always requires a defined PRIMARY KEY per table by the way, the reason is a bit complex to explain in a comment  you could check a answer off [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57233092/2548147) .. Simply said when defining you own PRIMARY KEY you avoid MySQL having to run that bad (blocking /slow) C/C++ code and get more performance..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I may define the composite index as `PK` that will also enforce data not being doubled (something I need) but then I won't be able to add the `id` column to `data_list` as `auto_increment` since that enforces to set it as `PK`. Assuming I actually need `id` as `PK` with auto inc, and composite index together.

Comment: *"What is the difference between Selectivity and Cardinality "* [Cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) is simple to explain it is just from the mathematics set/multiset thoery which MySQL also uses that way ... Selectivity is something else selectivity is simply said are the unique values within a total set with other words `SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT <column>) /  COUNT(*)  * 100) ... `.. , the higher the selectivity in this formula the better.. With other words over 80/90 and closer to 100 indexing will help, close to 0 to 50 do not index will not help most likely...

Comment: ... there is a fine balance it in as the MySQL optimizer is costs based there is a point where indexes can be used perform well and use lesser disk i/o .. And a point that even when you index MySQL saw that using that index would have more disk i/o and uses more resource .. For example  gender with M and F as data is a good example for do not index it will most likely not help.. MySQL would most likely go for a FULL scan anywhy when using `WHERE gender = 'M'`..

Comment: ... as bonus deploying [Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html) using the RANGE or LIST as partitioning types could proof usefull for those lower selectivity data like gender ..  Do not start using HASH/KEY as partitioning type it is not that great..

Comment: Cardinality typically refers to the number of values a column has. Selectivity is a quality a has predicate on a column; that is, how good the predicate is to select values from that column; for good index usage, you probably want a predicate that selects a low percentage of rows first, so it filters out much of the rows as soon as possible.

Comment: @RaymondNijland intersting case with gender = M/F. But this destroys my understanding of B-Tree. I would expect a tree that is based on power of 2 as most effective (fastest). I mean a B-Tree that has root split into 2 distinct values, and each of them have 2 children, and each of children have two children as well. So cardinality for each column that is a part of composite index should have cardinality 2times more elements than its parent column (a preceding column). But this results in having very poor selectivity. Is this the reason why index on gender = "M/F" brings no benefit?

Comment: @RaymondNijland if in compound index the following (child) column should have more elements than its preceding column then it if has 10 times instead of 2 times more distinct elements it still does not break the mentioned rule. The more distinct elements a single column has in composite index the more time needs to be spend on examining them for matching one(s) but maybe this is less CPU time consuming than nesting into child branches (columns on the right used for comp. index) which is the most significant if there are only 2 distinct elements per column? Is there any rule of thumb here?

Comment: you have to understand that `SELECT * FROM t WHERE gender = 'M'` always have to use that table file anyway.. When using  index MySQL needs to do random disk i/o on that table file to get that record meaning per record 4 - 10 ms disk delay instead of one time 4 - 10 ms delay (to open) and stream that table data at ~80 Mb per second when a FULL scan happens.. `SELECT COUNT(gender) FROM t WHERE gender = 'M'` on that other side indeed could possibly do a range scan on the index file..   Like i said before the MySQL optimizer is a heavy beast to understand i could write a book about to explain it..

Comment: @Jimmix - No.  Having a binary flag has zero impact on the structure of the BTree.  A secondary key has the PK tacked onto the end, so `INDEX(gender)` is virtually the same as `INDEX(gender, id)`.  Or, if you have `PRIMARY KEY(one, two), then it is `INDEX(gender, one, two)`.

Answer (score 0):

The cardinality and selectivity *of individual columns* is irrelevant in a *composite* index.

Think of the values in an InnoDB BTree index as the concatenation of the specified columns.

Populate an index with columns in roughly this order:

1. Column(s) tested with '=', even it it is a "flag".
2. `IN(const, ...)` -- The Optimizer may be able to hop through the index.
3. One "range".  No further ranges will be looked at.

A "Covering" index leads to some exceptions.

Your examples:

(A) Query for specific one, two, three, four:

```
    INDEX(one, two, three, four) -- in _any_ order
```

(B) Query for specific one, two, three and range of four

```
    INDEX(one, two, three,  -- put these first (=), in _any_ order
          four)             -- after the =s
```

the `ORDER BY` will happen to be handled, too

(C) Query for specific one, two and any three within range of four

```
    INDEX(one, two,         -- either order; including `three` would hurt
          four)             -- after the =s
```

But, this time, `ORDER BY two, three, four` cannot be also be handled; there will be a "filesort".

Alternatively (though unlikely), the Optimizer may choose to work with the `ORDER BY` instead of the `WHERE`.  In this case, this is optimal:

```
INDEX(two, three, four)  -- in the same order as the ORDER BY.
```

(D) Query with JOIN for specific one and two, three being on the list three_list and four within the range

This gets trickier because the Optimizer will pick which table to start with.  *Usually* it picks the one with more filtering available,  You are filtering on one, two, four in data_list?  But not at all on the other table.  So...

```
data_list: INDEX(one, two,   -- either order,
                 four)       -- range
three_list;  INDEX(l_three)
```

More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

"not having PK" -- Yes, this is bad.  But it does not have to be an `AUTO_INCREMENT`; that is a fallback in case you don't have a "natural" PK built from one (or more) columns.

`AUTO_INCREMENT` does not force the column to be the PK.  However, you must have *some* index *starting* with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.  That is the only constraint.

"alternative table design is also welcomed" -- We need to have a feel for what `one` (etc) really are.

If you have those 4 queries and want the optimal set of indexes:

```
INDEX(one, two, three, four)
INDEX(one, two,        four)
INDEX(     two, three, four)
```

(Other combos would do equally well.)

If you were more selective in the `SELECT` clause, then I would also talk about "covering" indexes.

Comment: Thank you for so extensive information, I'll populate table data and do performance tests + explain. I'll share the results. It may take a few days.